# when i run my flutter app ,there emerge a unexpected problem , error :

Tags: flutter, dart

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Could not resolve project :path_provider_macos.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app > project :path_provider
  >   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :path_provider_macos: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: what should i do ,i try more operation for this problem ,  but can't solve it

Comment: I just ran into this today - so am fortunate you asked this question just 3 days back and that @SOM posted an answer. Not sure why you got those down votes, certainly seems like a legit question to me.  [@SOM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62129310/2162226) provided a working solution, in my case with the `flutter pub cache repair`.  Unless I am missing something, I think you can mark it as the correct answer.  It certainly saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Some imports are missing. Try `flutter pub get` to update packages, or `flutter pub cache repair`, which will re-import all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

thank everyone , i get the solution about my problem : go to your Flutter sdk folder ,then go to .pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\ ,if there have a path_provider_macos-0.0.4 folder ,delete it ,if no ,you try go .pub-cache\hosted\pub.flutter-io.cn\ , and remove path_provider_macos-0.0.4 folder

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the folder you said,but show this wrong :  Project :flutter declares a dependency from configuration 'embed' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :path_provider_macos.

The following is detailed:

```
> A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':flutter:embed'.
      > Could not resolve project :path_provider_macos.
        Required by:
            project :flutter
         > Project :flutter declares a dependency from configuration 'embed' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :path_provider_macos.
      > Could not resolve project :path_provider_linux.
        Required by:
            project :flutter
         > Project :flutter declares a dependency from configuration 'embed' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :path_provider_linux.
```